# jquery blockUI seems not to effect on select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-blockui

I want to block the specific div by using the jquery blockUI. It seems it blocks the GUI but not effects the select element of html.

```
$('#divContainer').block({
    css: {
        border: 'none',
        padding: '15px',
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
        '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
        opacity: .5,
         color: '#fff'
         },
    message: "Readonly state."
});
```

**Updated:** i forget to mention that i am using it on samsung galaxy tab

Comment: I'm not sure what your HTML looks like, but if you check this fiddle example it seems to work ok.  http://jsfiddle.net/4aQyg/